# PHP Array и переменные

Tags: php, массивы

Имеется код:

```
<?php
    require __DIR__ . '/lib/autoload.php'; 
    use YooKassa\Client;

    $summa = 101.0
    $client = new Client();
    $client->setAuth('810090', 'test_ABCgLASEjg91hH_sDuc1My7ZpC7J-kl64p5nd7ezXpg');
    $payment = $client->createPayment(
        array(
            'amount' => array(
                'value' => $summa,
                'currency' => 'RUB',
            ),
            'confirmation' => array(
                'type' => 'redirect',
                'return_url' => 'https://www.merchant-website.com/return_url',
            ),
            'capture' => true,
            'description' => 'Заказ №1',
        ),
        uniqid('', true)
    );
```

Но он выдаёт ошибку:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$client' (T_VARIABLE) in E:\OpenServer\domains\test\yookassa.php on line 6
```

Помогите пожалуйста её исправить

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 $summa = 101.0;
               ^---- пропущена
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. Забыл про ; так как привык к python.